# Href tag with multiple assign values using get to other page using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

My problem is how to do multiple assigning of values on a variable inside an href tag.
In this line of code i have one get one value which is flightprice with the falue of price. My question is that what if I want to have multiple? Is it possible? two values on 1 href? without using jscript

```
 <td align="center">
        <a href="flights.php?flightprice=<?php echo $flights->price; ?>&action=getflight" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure')">GET FLIGHT</a>
</td>
```

Comment: If you check the url you will notice 2 values. In php you can you the $_GET to retrieve the values i.e. $fp = $_GET['flightprice']; $ac = $_GET['action'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way.

You could do something like this:

```
<a href="flights.php?flightprice:<?php echo $flights->price; ?>&location=<?php echo $flights->location; ?>&action=getflight">url</a>
```

To get values with the following:

```
$flightprice = isset($_GET['flightprice']) ? $_GET['flightprice'] : false;
$flightlocation = isset($_GET['flightlocation']) ? $_GET['flightlocation'] : false;
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : false;
```

Comment: Well, `...location=$flights->location&action...` will print just `location=$flights->location&action` and nothing more... Don't know  why you'd expect php to interpret it as a variable...

Comment: I wanna also suggest the shorthand for `<?php echo $va; ?>`, which is `<?=$flights->price?>`. Seems cleaner when mixing html and php.